# Searching a string via NSData

Tags: objective-c, string, nsdata

In order to search a string (haystack) for another substring (needle) and get all the ranges for the substring I have been loading the haystack into an `NSData` object and then also getting the `NSData` for the needle string and using `rangeOfData:options:range:` to search for the needle in the haystack.

```
// Get the data for the contents of the file, store error
NSError *error;
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:0 error:&error];
// Check for error
if (error) {
    // Handle it...
}
NSData *needleData = [needle dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, fileData.length);
while (searchRange.location < fileData.length) {
    NSRange needleRange = [fileData rangeOfData:needleData options:0 range:searchRange];
    if (needleRange != NSNotFound) {
        // Found one, use the range...
    } else {
        // Otherwise there are no more to be found, bail out
        break;
    }
}
```

Generally the needle ranges found using `rangeOfData:` are the same as the range of the needle string in the haystack string however this assumes that each character is 1 byte however some Unicode characters are not and are 2 (or more) bytes, for example ✔ and ✘. This results in the range of the needle in the data not being the same as the range of the needle in the string.

Is there anyway to accurately get the range of the string from its range in the data or should I be looking at using a different algorithm? I tested a number of methods for searching the string itself and this came up fastest (compared to using `rangeOfString:`, `NSRegularExpression`, KMP, Boyer-Moore and Boyer-Moore-Horspool).

Comment: Some characters even use 3 or 4 UTF-8 bytes :)

Comment: And rangeOfData is significantly faster than rangeOfString?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @MartinR Yep `rangeOfString` is significantly slower. From what I've read it uses a naïve string search whilst NSData uses Boyer-Moore.

Comment: @HotLicks To get the all the ranges of a string within another string (most efficiently), for search functionality.

Comment: @Joshua: Just an idea: Convert both haystack and needle to NSData using the NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding. Then each character has exactly 4 bytes.

Comment: @MartinR A great idea and worked very nicely. Could you post as an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)* Convert both haystack and needle string to `NSData` with the `NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding`. Then every character occupies exactly 4 bytes in the data blob.

Answer (score 1):

Try `strstr(3)` with pointer arithmetic. With some help from `strchr(3)` you will be able to massively parallelizing this.